# If $X_t$ is a Markov Chain with parameter $\theta$, why $P(X_t\mid X_{t-1}, \ldots, X_1, \theta) = P(X_t\mid X_{t-1}, \theta)$?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose that $X_t$ is a Markov Chain with a transition matrix depending on parameters $\theta = (\theta_0, \theta_1)$. Then, for all $t \geq 1$, the distribution of $X_t$ given $X_1, \ldots, X_{t-1}$ only depends on $X_{t-1}$. The transition matrix is:

$$P =
\pmatrix{\theta_0& 1-\theta_0 \\
1-\theta_1 & \theta_1}$$

Now, based on the assumptions above, I am wondering **why it is the case** that:

$$
P(X_t|X_{t-1}, \ldots, X_1, \theta_1, \theta_0) = P(X_t|X_{t-1}, \theta_1, \theta_0)
$$

?

I thought that a Markov Chain only tells us that

$$
P(X_t|X_{t-1}, \ldots, X_1) = P(X_t|X_{t-1})
$$

and nothing about when we have extra parameters in the conditional part. This leads me to wonder, is the definition of a Markov Chain one of **conditional independence** rather than independence?

In other words, does just the definition of $X_t$ being a Markov Chain directly lead to the relation:

$$
P(X_t|X_{t-1}, \ldots, X_1, \theta_1, \theta_0) = P(X_t|X_{t-1}, \theta_1, \theta_0)
$$

or is it derived?

Comment: You seem to be misled by uncertain notations. The hypothesis in your post is that $$P_{\theta_1, \theta_0}(X_t\mid X_{t-1}, \ldots, X_1) = P_{\theta_1, \theta_0}(X_t\mid X_{t-1})$$ for every $(\theta_1, \theta_0)$, which is exactly assuming that, for every $(\theta_1, \theta_0)$, $(X_t)$ is a Markov chain under the probability $P_{\theta_1, \theta_0}$. Thus: simply the definition.

Comment: Normally you'd use a semicolon before the thetas, not a comma, to indicate that they're parameters (or use the notation Did uses).

Comment: ((Additionally, note that the symbol denoting conditionings is `\mid`.))